# Amp подключение пользовательского JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amp

Подскажите,

- Как на amp страницах сохранить функционал сайта?
- Можно ли подключать к этим страницам свои скрипты?
- Если мне к примеру нужно оставить слайдер, и адаптивное меню по
  клику, это все нужно переделывать из модулей `amp.js`?
- И еще вопрос по поводу яндекс и гугл метрики: на amp их подключить
  не получится?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вопрос:** «Можно ли подключать к этим страницам свои скрипты?».

**Ответ:** Нет. Пользовательский JavaScript не поддерживается, или не разрешен.

---

**Вопрос:** «Если мне к примеру нужно оставить слайдер, и адаптивное меню по клику, это все нужно переделывать из модулей amp.js?».

**Ответ:** Верно, все нужно переделывать. Делать функционал используя компоненты AMP. 
Пример подключенных компонентов AMP, в теге `<head>` страницы:

```html
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-image-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-image-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-youtube" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-youtube-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
```

---

**Вопрос:** «И еще вопрос по поводу яндекс и гугл метрики ? на amp их подключить не получится?»

**Ответ:**

- [AMP on Google](https://developers.google.com/amp/), при этом, вы считаете, что может не быть
  поддержки Google Analytics? [Подробнее...](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/?hl=ru).
- [Яндекс Метрика](https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/code/install-counter-amp.xml)

---

**Вопрос:** «Подскажите, как на amp страницах сохранить функционал сайта?».

**Ответ:** Если страницы сайта сделаны без расчета AMP варианта, большую часть функционала не сохранить. Но это касается не только функционала. На AMP страницах есть ограничения на HTML/CSS/JavaScript код. Например в HTML ряд тегов запрещен, и нужно использовать специальные AMP теги. Поэтому, с"обычного" сайта не перенести(без переделывания) не только функционал, а даже простой HTML код, а порой и CSS код.

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный ответ )

Comment: @Denis Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Не своевременно, теперь js поддерживается. 
https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript/
Пример:

```
<amp-script height="500" width="320" layout="container" src="https://www.example/js.js" >
<form method="post" class="grass-calc-form calc-title" id="calcForm" action-xhr="https://www.example/js.js" >
</form>
</amp-script>
```

Но не все поддерживается. Что-то простое на JS можно написать, если у вас используется JQuery, то придется переделывать. Тот же `.checked` не поддерживается например.